# Extend Pyduino over wireless network

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server

I followed a [guide](https://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-Arduino-with-python-based-web-API-No-p/) to control my arduino uno using a python web server API ([flask](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/)), and it works like a charm using the COM port on my PC. I would like to extend this over the network with an ESP8266 module so i can have a web server handling my project's event scheduling and hard work using python/html/css/js (anything supported/needed) and have the arduino as a client receiving the server data and acting accordingly. I am not limited to this method as it seems pretty hard to generalize over the network (Use a virtual COM port on the server side and forward the arduino using the router?//i  have to specify where the arduino port is located) so any other way to setup a Web server handling the event triggering and sending the ON/OFF information to my arduino (i just need to trigger a relay) is accepted.

Comment: There are many example how to set up a webserver on an Arduino using an ESP and also about doing this directly with an ESP (since most ESPs are more capable than most Arduinos). When you have a webserver running on the Arduino, sending information to it is nothing more than a web request. Have you looked into this? If yes, why is it not fitting for you?

Comment: I was thinking about using the arduino as a web client listening directly to my server and couldn't find exactly what i wanted but then i thought about what you said. I guess i can setup arduino/esp as a web server that handles requests and have another website that sends the requests when certain events are triggered.

Comment: I quickly searched for "arduino web request ESP" and found some promising sites. If think, you should look more into it. You write something about a virtual com port over wifi in your question, but honestly I think you would be going the hard way trying that. On a TCPIP network it is the easiest thing to simply do web requests.

Comment: I cant understand whats the best way to deal with my problem. Can i set up the arduino to constantly "listen" to a website for a specific event or do i have to use it as a server, port forward it and send the triggered events that way